# Proving integers are relatively prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $a,b,c$ be nonzero integers.  Suppose $a$ divides $(b+c)$ and $(b,c) = 1$.  Prove that $(a,b) = 1$.

My thoughts: Use the fact that the G.C.D of $a$ and $b$ is the smallest positive integer that can be written in the form $ax + by$ for integers $x$ and $y$. Having trouble with the set up.

Comment: the tag abstract algebra is wrong cuz integer properties are elementary

Comment: thats the name of my course so just going by that. sorry.

Comment: from now on D-Man

Comment: @janmarqz: I believe many introductory courses on abstract algebra teach elementary number theory as well, though indeed it can't be called "abstract".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $d|a$ and $d|b$ then, as $a|b+c$ we get that $d|b+c$.

Thus you have $d|b$ and $d|b+c$. Combine this with gcd$(b,c)=1$ and you are done.

Comment: you are referring to d as what? the GCD?

Comment: @D-Man Well, what does it mean that $d|a$ and $d|b$? ;)

Comment: haha of course.  just having a hard time understanding the concept behind the thm. and also how this definitely proves it.  If you could elaborate any further that would help.  Its more concept understanding if anything

Comment: and you also kind of worked backwards which was different than what I have seen as well

Comment: @D-Man This is pretty standard. You start with the gcd of a and b(and I denote it by $d$ just to save some time, much easier to write) and after some computations you get it is 1....

Answer (score 0):

From $(b,c)=1$ you know that there exist integers $p,q$ with $1=bp+cq$. From $a|b+c$ there exists $r$ with $b+c=ar$. So $c=ar-b$ and then
$$
1=bp+cq=bp+(ar-b)q=b(p-q)+arq.
$$
So $(a,b)=1$.

Comment: do you mean 1 = bp + cq at the beginning?

Comment: what statement definitively makes the conclusion that (a,b)=1.  seems vague

Comment: It's not vague at all. Given $a,b$, one has that $(a,b)=1$ if and only if there exist $p,q$ with $1=ap+bq$.

Comment: is it right to say this is true because of the last line b(p-q) + arq because it is in the form of ap + bq? and you assume the p-q and rq are integers?

Comment: Yes, And $p-q$ is an integer because it is a difference of integers, and $rq$ is a product of integers, so again an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another proof:

Note: $(b,c) = 1$, then there exists two integers: $x$ and $y$ such that $bx + cy = 1$

Consider $d = (a,b)$
So $d|a$ and $d|b$
We also have $a|(b+c)$ so there exists an integer k such that $b+c = ak$
Means that $c = ak - b$

$d|a$ implies $d|ak$ so $d|(ak - b)$, thus $d|c$

$d|c$ and $d|b$ implies that $d|(bx+cy)$ thus $d|1$
Now it's obvious that d = 1, since d is strictly positive.

Comment: should be c= ak-b correct?

Comment: Yes you are right thanks I' have corrected it now.